# Convert Object to Array angularjs with dynamic value

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-scope

```
{"13":"I","14":"E","15":"V","16":"G"}
```

to:

```
['I', 'E', 'V', 'G']
```

where the 0 property of objects have the array of 1 and 2 objects? Is there a way to do that?

```
<div ng-repeat="data in data" >
<label>
<input ng-model="student[data.stn_id]"  ng-true-value="'{{data.stn_name}}'" ng-false-value="" /><span>{{data.stn_name}}</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                       {{student}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not clear. Put more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = {"13":"I","14":"E","15":"V","16":"G"};

var result = [];
angular.forEach(x, function (value, key){
    result.push(value);
});

console.log(result); // [I,E,V,G]
```

Comment: Didn't get that. It should work. What's the issue ? Are you getting any error ?

Comment: NO, I AM GET ANY ERROR MY OUT IS COME IN OBJECT BUT I GET DATA IN ARRAY

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand what you are trying to say. Can you please make your question clear. Just mention the data you are getting from service and to which form it should be converted.

Comment: thank you for replay and ans me :var result = [];
    angular.forEach(x, function (element) {
        result.push(element);
    });
    return x.join(',');
    console.log(result);

Answer (score 1):

Using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#values)

```
var d={"13":"I","14":"E","15":"V","16":"G"};
_.values(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var a = {"13":"I", "14":"E", "15":"V", "16":"G"};
        var b = [];
        angular.forEach(a, function(val, key){
          b.push(val);
        })
        console.log(b); // check the output ['I', 'E', 'V', 'G']
```